# Execute Stored procedure in azure server

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

How to execute an sample stored procedure in azure server.

I am using cosmos db emulator and whenever i try to execute a sample sp i get this error

> Requests originating from scripts cannot reference partition keys other than the one for which client request was submitted.

## Stored procedure

```
function createToDoItem(itemToCreate) {
    var context = getContext();
    var container = context.getCollection();
    console.log("success");
    var itemToCreate={
        "Id": null,
        "UserAccountID": "1742",
        "FirstName": "Sanjeev",
        "LastName": "S",
        "Phone": "12345678",
        "Location": "",
        "StreetAddress": "vcbgvbvc",
       };

itemToCreate.partitionKey = "UserAccountID";

    var accepted = container.createDocument(container.getSelfLink(),
        itemToCreate,
        function (err, itemCreated) {
            if (err) throw new Error('Error test' + err.message);
            context.getResponse().setBody(itemCreated.id)
        });
    if (!accepted) return;
}
```

the sample stored procedure also fails to get the desired results. linking the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55789136/stored-procedure-azure-cosmos-db-returns-empty-collection)

Comment: When you're executing the stored procedure, what's the value of `PartitionKey` you're passing?

Comment: @GauravMantri UserAccountID

Comment: Sorry, I meant the value of `PartitionKey` attribute.

Comment: attribute?. I didn't get you

Comment: If you look at the document you're trying to create above, which attribute in that document is the `PartitionKey` attribute? Is it `UserAccountID`?

Comment: yes. UserAccountID is the attribute

Comment: So what's the value you're passing when executing the stored procedure? You will need to specify the same value (`1742` in your case) as that in the document. @JayGong's answer is correct.

Comment: that answer did not work for me. still getting the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sanjeev S,based on the issue message:

> Requests originating from scripts cannot reference partition keys
>   other than the one for which client request was submitted.

It claims that your partition key in your document needs to match the partition key setting  of your collection.

For example,your collection's partition key is `/name`,

[image]

Then you need to exclude the name property in your inserted document and provide the partition key like this when you execute the SP.

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: @SanjeevS Strangely,I tested on my side successfully. Have you checked my detailed function?

Comment: @SanjeevS Or remove all the existences now and re-create it following my steps?

Comment: even the sample stored proceudre is not getting the desired results.It shows no docs found. is there any relation with this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55789136/stored-procedure-azure-cosmos-db-returns-empty-collection

Comment: @SanjeevS Could you please join this link:https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192202/cosmos-db-emulator-sp

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the the partition key to your document inside the stored procedure as you're dealing with a dynamic JS object.

```
doc.partitionKey = 'some_partition_key'
```

Comment: I am trying to execute the sp directly from the cosmos db emulator

Comment: still you could set it

Comment: @Sajetharan

added stored procedure in question

Comment: did it fix the issue?